# Throwing destructor compilable by C++98 and C++1x. Is there a better way?

Tags: c++, c++11, cross-platform, c++98

Is there a clean way or workaround to achieve a throwing destructor compilable by both `c++98` and `c++1x` compilers which is cross-platform and does not produce warnings?

#### Given

There is a legacy class representing an error code, which throws if it is not handled. To achieve this it uses a throwing destructor.

#### Goal

A cross-platform (g++, VC++) implementation that compiles and works with both older `c++98` compilers (thank you MS for the WindowsCE) as well as with compilers supporting `c++1x`. Ideally, it should not produce any warnings.

#### Problem

The problem is that since `c++11` all destructors are non-throwing by default (will terminate at run-time if an exception is thrown). Workaround is `noexcept(false)`, but it is not available in `c++98`. On the other hand `c++98` has exception specifications, which are generally considered bad and are deprecated since `c++11` E.g., see: [Why are exception specifications bad?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114338/why-are-exception-specifications-bad).

#### Current workaround

```
class ThrowingErrorCode
{
public:
    ...
// silence the VC exception specification warning
// we need to use exception specification for a throwing destructor, so that it would compile with both c++98 and c++11
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4290 )
#endif

   ~ThrowingErrorCode() throw(ErrorCodeException)
   {
      ...
      throw ErrorCodeException("Must handle error code");
   }

// enable the warning again
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning( pop )
#endif   
};
```

I don't quite like it, as it needs to suppress warnings and uses deprecated exception specification. Could you please tell me if there a better/cleaner way of doing this?

---

<sup>This is my first StackOverflow question. If you have any advice on improving the question, please let me know :-)</sup>

Comment: Firstly: destructors should not throw exceptions. End of story. This is broken design. Secondly: `#define THROWING_DESTRUCTOR nothrow(false)` or `#define THROWING_DESTRUCTOR`, selected based on the compiler, and used to declare all destructors.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: This class obviously exists for RAII-like enforcement of error handling. All of a sudden a throwing destructor is sane.

Comment: @Joshua: But what if the destructor has been called **because** of an exception already thrown ? If destructor does throw again, we have two exceptions on hands.

Comment: @informaticienzero: Then the position your process is in is already unrecoverable.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "_This is broken design_" why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could define a simple macro to effect a throwing exception specification:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#  define MAY_THROW noexcept(false)
#else
#  define MAY_THROW
#endif
```

Usage:

```
struct X
{
    ~X() MAY_THROW { /* ... */ }
    //   ^^^^^^^^^
};
```

Non-conforming compilers may not set the `__cplusplus` macro correctly, in which case you may need to compare against additional vendor macros. For example, some versions of MSVC++ can use this code:

```
#if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#  define MAY_THROW noexcept(false)
#elif defined(_MSC_VER) && _MSC_VER >= 1800
#  define MAY_THROW noexcept(false)
#else
#  define MAY_THROW
#endif
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but without explicit exception specification this will terminate at run-time when compiled with `c++11`

Comment: @AMA: Which is why you do provide an explicit, throwing exception specification for C++11.

Comment: @AMA: Check the value of the `__cplusplus` macro. It's possible that that compiler isn't conforming and sets it to something bogus. In that case, consult your vendor documentation for additional macros you can use to identify that compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the approach suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41427247/1597714).
It will still produce a warning when `c++03` is used with `gcc` (see [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/FThbozNGPej5cVRj)). Since I don't use this configuration, it will do.

I used boost's `BOOST_NO_NOEXCEPT` macro for the cross-platform check of `noexcept` support.
Here's how [it looks](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1iHXkQhSvDPLD5OT):

```
#include <boost/detail/workaround.hpp>

#if defined BOOST_NO_NOEXCEPT
#  define MAY_THROW
#else
#  define MAY_THROW noexcept(false)
#endif
```

Comment: Using a library to deal with the compiler uglyness for the win!